# Fragment with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I develop a fragment that him content is dynamic?
Eg. The default content of the fragment is three `<Button>`, depending of the activity that the fragment is it, the fragment can have only two `<button>` or only one `<button>` visible.

How can I control this "conditional visibility" of the content?

Also, there is a way to control this "conditional visibility" of the buttons depending of the state of activity?

---

What is the best way to make it? Can I create a fragment xml with all buttons and control the visibility of them in activity? Or I insert and remove the button through the activity or through of fragment itself?

Sorry for my english, I am a Brazilian user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you declare all the buttons you require in the layout.
Then by your requirement you set the **visbility** parameter of that particular button dynamically in your fragment code.

Something like:

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can also see some guidelines for building flexible UI here:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Fragments can have the newInstance method using which you can create new instance of the fragment with the parameters you wish, so you can pass an array of booleans to the newInstance method from which you can set the visibility of the buttons

newInstance method to push the flags to bundle.

```
public static final String ARG_BUTTON_VISIBILITY_FLAGS = "visibility_flags";

public static MyFragment newInstance(Boolean[] param1) {
    AboutUsFragment fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBooleanArray(ARG_BUTTON_VISIBILITY_FLAGS, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

You can access this data in the onCreate of your fragment. like this

```
private Boolean[] mVisibilityFlags;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mVisibilityFlags = getArguments().getBooleanArray(ARG_BUTTON_VISIBILITY_FLAGS);
    }
}
```

And instead of instantiating your fragment like so `MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment()` you instatiate it like this `MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(buttonVisibilityFlags);` so this way you have successfully passed the flags to your fragment.

Now based on the position of the button in your view you set its visbility accordingly say if the button position is 3, you do `button3.setVisibility(mVisibilityFalgs[3])`

Answer (score 0):

If the fragments are differing in much detail, just create two (or more) fragments.

The best way to let the fragment know about what to display is by using arguments. [Here's an article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6996-fragment-and-activity-working-together.html?start=1) about that. Basically the activity will add an argument like "DISPLAY_FULL": true or false, and then you get that argument from the bundle in `onCreate(...)` and store it in a field. Then in `onCreateView(...)` you check the value of the field and hide / show UI elements depending on that.